# How to delete (rm) files on a CIFS mount when filename contains a colon (:) or other special characters?

Tags: linux, command-line, samba, file-management, cifs

On my LAN, I have a Synology NAS with encrypted shared folders. They are mounted on my Debian computer through CIFS (NFS is only available for unencryted shared folders).

```
//<NAS_IP_ADDRESS>/<SHARED_FOLDER> /mnt/<MOUNT_FOLDER> cifs _netdev,credentials=<PATH_TO_CREDENTIALS>,iocharset=utf8,mapchars,uid=<UID>,gid=<GID>,setuids 0 0
```

When I try to manipulate (`rm`, `stat`, `mv`…) a file containing a special character (most often a colon), I get an error

```
rm: cannot remove '<FILENAME>': No such file or directory
```

What can I do to solve this problem? Probably changing a mounting parameter or some option in the samba configuration?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which SMB version are you using? Have you tried _removing_ the `mapchars` option?

Comment: I'm using `samba 2:4.5.16` and `mount.cifs 6.7`.

Comment: I tried removing `mapchars` and it mostly solved my problem.

Now, many of the files I had this problem with are duplicated on my NAS. Sometimes I cannot find any difference in the name (probably because they use graphically identical characters from two different unicode ranges), sometimes one shows the correct character and the other shows a dotted rectangle. How can I find and automatically deduplicate these fales?

Answer (score 0):

Just had the same issue. File is shown in the directory listing, but cannot be opened / deleted. No trick with find or inodes worked.

Then I used `smbclient` instead of cifs mount, the filename is shown as in DOS 8.3 format, but delete command still can't find it. But using `del *` in that directory (it was the only file left) successfully removed the file.

Listing cifs mount:

```
ls: 'VK? NEWS - 2009.pdf.2018-12-03T01:24:59+01:00.snapshot.gz': No such file or directory
total 897
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 891372 Nov 13  2012 VK? NEWS - 2009.pdf.2018-12-03T01:24:59+01:00.snapshot.gz
```

Listing/deleting via smbclient:

```
smb: \main\rdiff-backup-data\increments\userfiles\> dir
  .                                   D        0  Wed Oct 16 00:01:34 2019
  ..                                  D        0  Tue Oct 15 23:06:52 2019
  V9AGMV~L.GZ                         A   891372  Tue Nov 13 11:35:24 2012

                104857600 blocks of size 1024. 30534775 blocks available

smb: \main\rdiff-backup-data\increments\userfiles\> del V9AGMV~L.GZ
NT_STATUS_NO_SUCH_FILE listing \main\rdiff-backup-data\increments\userfiles\V9AGMV~L.GZ

smb: \main\rdiff-backup-data\increments\userfiles\> del *

smb: \main\rdiff-backup-data\increments\userfiles\> dir
  .                                   D        0  Wed Oct 16 00:05:42 2019
  ..                                  D        0  Tue Oct 15 23:06:52 2019

                104857600 blocks of size 1024. 30534775 blocks available
```